# Omitting data by Year in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with missing data after year 2015, so I need to remove NaN values and entries after 2015(2016-2020). I can remove NaN values using this code

```
gamedata[gamedata == "N/A"] = NA
gamedata <- na.omit(gamedata)
```

How to omit data after 2015? Here is data sample

```
       Rank                        Name Platform Year    Genre          Publisher NA_Sales EU_Sales JP_Sales Other_Sales Global_Sales
1 14131  Zatch Bell! Electric Arena      GBA 2003 Fighting          Banpresto     0.02     0.01        0        0.00         0.03
```

Comment: Base R: `subset(gatedata, Year < 2015)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use dplyr's filter for that.

```r
library(dplyr)
gamedata <- gamedata %>% filter(Year<2015)
```

If you are unfamiliar with dplyr, strongly recommend to have a look at https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/, specially the Cheat Sheets and the [example sections](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html#examples) of each function, such as filter()

Answer (score 0):

This is a Base R approach to remove rows with `NaN` in Year.

```
gamedata <- gamedata[!is.nan(gamedata$Year), ]
```

This removes rows with Year beyond 2015.

```
gamedata <- gamedata[gamedata$Year <= 2015, ]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to filter out years over a given value.

Comment: Oh you're right. I guess it's supposed to remove NaN, not NA. Thanks for the headsup.